# Determine if data type/structure is the same as basic description of the data?

Tags: python, types, structure, verify

Imagine a simple data description label that is used to describe the type of data that is being exchanged between two systems.  In order to have data integrity between these systems (which are also intended to be extendible by the creation of new modules) they must have a simple description of the data type and structure that they output.  Given that these systems mostly handle command line commands and outputs, the data types need not be too complex.

Because the language this system is written in is Python, the simple data types are bool, int, float, str, list, and dict.  Lists and dicts must be explicitly defined with what data type they contain (ie list(float) for a list of floats or dict(str, list(str)) for a dictionary that maps strings to lists of strings.

When a system is passed data from another system it checks whether the data it was passed follows the data description that the module has for it's input, if it does then proceed otherwise throw and error.  A few small examples below:

```
verify("int", 1)                            -> True
verify("int", "1")                          -> False
verify("list(int)", [1, 2, 3])              -> True
verify("list(int)", [])                     -> True
verify("dict(str,int)", {"a": 1})           -> True
verify("dict(str,int)", {"b": 1, "c": "d"}) -> False
```

Obviously recursion is the method to solve this problem if I were to write it from scratch and it's not too difficult of a problem, but I was wondering if there is already a module for this sort of functionality.

Comment: There is no module that I'm aware of, but this would be an interesting and useful project. I'm tired of using nested isinstance() checks. If no one answers this with a plausible scenario, I'll see if I can't make time to do it.

Comment: @Goodies I'm already mostly through it's initial creation, I just realized I might be doing more work that I need to. Looking for modules to do your work for you is useful for almost every non-trivial task.

Comment: You _might_ be able to get some help via the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.

Comment: @Goodies I posted a quick mock-up that passes all the tests given in the question, I'm going to be working on a more robust version later today.  If you wanted to contribute it'll be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far, it was packaged better into a "TypeLabel" object before but I compressed it into one function to follow more closely to the function specified with the test-cases in the answer.  The function passes the few simple test cases above but provides no error checking of an improper data type specification for example.  I'll make a more robust version later today. Not that this is the place for critique but if you see any glaring errors feel free to point them out.

```
def verify(specification, test_data):
    typenames = {"tuple": tuple, "dict": dict, "list": list, "str": str, "int": int, "bool": bool, "float": float}

    def interpret_spec(spec):
        def find_separators(spec):
            seps = []
            depth = 0
            for i in range(len(spec)):
                if spec[i] == ',' and depth == 0:
                    seps.append(i)
                elif spec[i] == '(':
                    depth += 1
                elif spec[i] == ')':
                    depth -= 1
            return seps

        def recurse_type(spec):
            seps = find_separators(spec)
            if len(seps) != 0:
                sub_specs = [""]
                for i in range(len(spec)):
                    if i in seps:
                        sub_specs.append("")
                    else:
                        sub_specs[-1] += spec[i]
                if spec[-1] == "":
                    spec = spec[:-1]
                return tuple([recurse_type(sub_spec) for sub_spec in sub_specs])
            spec_name = spec
            if "(" in spec:
                spec_name = spec[:spec.find("(")]
                sub_spec = spec[spec.find("(")+1:spec.rfind(")")]
                return {spec_name: recurse_type(sub_spec)}
            else:
                return spec_name

        return recurse_type(spec.replace(" ", "").strip())

    def recurse_verify(spec, data):
        try:
            if isinstance(spec, str):
                return isinstance(data, typenames[spec])
            elif isinstance(spec, dict):
                datatype_name = spec.keys()[0]
                if not isinstance(data, typenames[datatype_name]):
                    return False
                if datatype_name == "list":
                    for item in data:
                        if not recurse_verify(spec[datatype_name], item):
                            return False
                elif datatype_name == "dict":
                    for key in data:
                        if not recurse_verify(spec[datatype_name][0], key) or not recurse_verify(spec[datatype_name][1], data[key]):
                            return False
                elif datatype_name == "tuple":
                    if len(spec[datatype_name]) != len(data):
                        return False
                    for i in range(len(data)):
                        subtype = spec[datatype_name][i]
                        subdata = data[i]
                        if not recurse_verify(subtype, subdata):
                            return False
        except TypeError:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    return recurse_verify(interpret_spec(specification), test_data)
```

Comment: Nice! I might even accept a parameter of additional (custom) classes to test those as well.

Comment: @Goodies That's a good idea, especially considering I'm going for an extensible solution.